# Extracting unique values from a range, but repeating each value x times before next unique value

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, duplicates, formula

I have a bit of a strange scenario. I am attempting to create a formula that, as the title suggests, that is supposed to extra unique values from a range (without blanks) but repeat them a set number (let's say 5) of times before returning the next unique value. For example, this is the A1:A6 (should be top to down but for the sake of space, I formatted like this):

`1,2,2,3,3,3`

What I want is a formula to drag them down to this on Column B.

`1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3`

As reference, the formula I'm currently using to return the unique values to repeat once, without blanks, is this:

`=INDEX(A1:A6, MATCH(0, IF(ISBLANK(A1:A6), 1, COUNTIF(B$1:$B1, A1:A6)), 0))`

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Store the Unique Values as an output of a Named Range(put the formula in there), and then do the repeating logic on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$6)/((COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$6)<5)*($A$1:$A$6<>"")),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: This. This is it. Thank you so much! I've never used AGGREGATE before, good to know about it!